# Problem with interface in XNA game project

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

Here is a part mof my code:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

.
.
.

    public virtual bool CheckCollision(ICollidable i_Source)
    {
        bool collided = false;
        ICollidable2D source = i_Source as 2DICollidable; 
        if (source != null)
        {
            collided = source.Bounds.Intersects(this.Bounds);
        }

        return collided;
    }
```

For some reason, there is an error about using ICollided2D.
Why does it don't recognize this kind of variable? Do I miss any "using" statment?

Comment: You should be more precise. What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: Do you mean a compilation error? (received when trying to compile the code), or a runtime error when actually executing it ?

Answer (score 2):

Either this is a typing mistake:

`ICollidable2D source = i_Source as 2DICollidable;`

Or you a missing an `_` before `2DICollidable`, so it becomes `_2DICollidable` as you can't start an identifier with a number.

Answer (score 1):

> 2DICollidable

What is this? I dont think normal identifiers can start with number. Heck even SO code-highlighter shows it in red.